# pluging value to override vimrc

Tags: vimrc, ftplugin

in my ftplugin, I have code:

```
  if executable('fprettify')
    au BufWritePre <buffer> :silent %!fprettify --silent
  else
    :let choice=confirm("fprettify doesn't exists! Install fprettify?", "&Yes\n&No(use fallback)")
    if choice == 1
      :execute ':!pip3 install fprettify --user -q'
      au BufWritePre <buffer> :silent %!fprettify --silent
    elseif choice == 2
      let g:VimF90Linter = 1
    endif
```

Now, if users have `g:VimF90Linter = 2` in `~.vimrc`, but does not have `fprettify`, he may still choose `1`. In that case, the prompt is appearing everytime he opens a fortran file. How can I override this behaviour, i.e. the prompt should disappear and irrespective of value of `g:VimF90Linter` set in `~/.vimrc`, it should be 1 as set in the plugin.

Is this possible?

Comment: There is nothing in your snippet that depends on `g:VimF90Linter`.

Comment: Er, I wouldnt recommend trying to force your settings on users (though I’m not sure if that’s a vim global or a global unique to your plugin)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble: it was global unique to my plugin, now modified to `b:` anyway. And I am not forcing my setting to user. That is why the option is.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry I don't understand the specifics of your question.

At best I guess you want to cache the previous user choice, that could have been done in the ftplugin or the user `.vimrc`.

`get(g:, 'varname', defaultvalue)` may help here.

May be something like the following?

```
function! s:register_linter() abort
  augroup FortranLinter
    au!
    au BufWritePre <buffer> :silent %!fprettify --silent
  aug END
  let g:VimF90Linter = get(g:, 'VimF90Linter', 'use')
endfunction

function! s:install_on_the_fly() abort
  :!pip3 install fprettify --user -q
  " Make sure to not ask again if pip fails
  if ! v:shell_error
    let g:VimF90Linter = 'ignore'
  endif
  return ! v:shell_error " returns 1 iff pip succeeds
endfunction

let linter = get(g:, 'VimF90Linter', '')
if executable('fprettify') && linter != 'ignore'
  call s:register_linter()
elseif linter == 'install on the fly' " or may be not empty and != 'ignore'?
  let dummy = s:install_on_the_fly() && s:register_linter()
elseif empty(linter)
  let choice = confirm(....)
  if choice == 1
    let dummy = s:install_on_the_fly() && s:register_linter()
  else
    let g:VimF90Linter = 'ignore'
  endif
endif
```

IMO, as with the fizz-buzz test, you'll have to be explicit and quite possibly state all the possible cases and subcases.